# Ultrasonic waves through moving fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, continuum-mechanics

By sending a ultrasonic wave though a fluid, the time it takes to propagate can be converted into a fluid velocity.

Since i don't know where to begin, i have two primary questions:

1. When the wave is propagating through a given fluid flow, can the wave be modeled as massless? in effect moving with the fluid flow.
2. Can the wave be modeled as particles a lot of particles (finite infinite), leaving from a point in every direction?

I Hope you can help me or maybe guide me in the right direction :)

Comment: Question not clear beginning from sentence 1. Please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of rewording the question as requested?

For the moment let's not worry about the fact that it's ultrasound you are interested in.  Linear Acoustics can be is a perturbation to the fields of fluid mechanics.  In fact that is how it is derived from "first principles".

You typically get a 4-dim wave equation without a mass term in the special relativistic sense, so yes it is a "massless" field in that sense but I'm not sure that helps.

The science of linear acoustics in moving fluids goes back more than 100 years and there are text books out there entitled "Acoustics in Moving Fluid Media" or "Ray Tracing in Moving Fluid Media" so I think if you search you'll find a lot out there.  Search the JASA (Journal of the Acoustical Society of America) data base.

The basics are that the sound moves with the fluid.  Locally one has c*n+v = dx/dt, where c is the local sound speed, n the wavefront normal, v the local fluid velocity vector, and dx/dt the ray path derivative (x is meant to be a vector).  There are many ways to express this in terms of rays or fields.

The General Relativity community has noticed a correspondence between acoustics in a moving fluid and massless scalar fields on curved space-times (but that probably doesn't help you).  The point is that the problem is well defined.  The "acoustic" field has a life of its own separated from the background fluid profile.

That said: Ultrasound will probably excite the medium, perhaps being absorbed by some amount depending on the exact frequency and properties of the fluid.  For example, in air there are well known modeling for the attenuation coefficient as a function of frequency, humidity, temperature, and Nitrogen and Oxygen content etc.  So, your ultrasound may propagate as any other sound but be attenuated differently (you need to check that).  Next, will it really be LINEAR.  What strength of ultrasound are you interested in?  From a purely computational point of view you could ignore this is adopt the standard equations and they should tell you something about the geometry of acoustic field motion in the moving fluid.  But you need to check the other details.  Just out of curiosity are you looking at a sonar application, using a phased array?  I've done experiments and modeling of these systems and obtained good match between data and models, good predictability using standard acoustics equations mentioned in this answer.